# How to combine ODE parameters values from several estimations?

Tags: experimental-physics, transfer-function, cost-estimation

I would like to perform parameters estimation for a differential equation from experiment. If the value of these parameters are obtained from several experiments (repetitions) where for each experiment different final cost function is obtained, how can I calculated the final parameters values from these experiments? 
Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered the tolerance on each input value? What is the effect of all these on the output?